# Kotlin filter method

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, filter

I have a list of ids say of size 10
and I have another list of items I want an efficient way to remove items that match any of those 10 ids

```
  val list=items.filter { id== 1||id==3... and so on but in a more efficient way }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use predicate and filterTo method

```
//list of things you don't want in your filtered list
 val listOfIds= listOf(312,264,309,297,233,262,149,156,214,350,316,315)
//a predicate used in filterTo function
  private val someFilteringCondition = { num: Int ->listOfIds.contains(num) }

//list that we will filter into (it will contains filtered list
private val filteredPublishers = mutableListOf<SegmentModel>()

 items.filterNotTo(filteredPublishers,someFilteringCondition )
                        adpater?.publishersChanged(it)
```

now filteredPublishers list constains items that doesn't have mentioned ids

Answer (score 4):

Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection except the elements contained in the given elements collection:

```
fun main() {
    val ids = listOf(20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
    val removeIds = listOf(30, 60)
    val result = ids - removeIds
    println(result)   // [20, 40, 50]
}
```

Or with substract:

```
val result = ids subtract removeIds
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are dealing with a `MutableList`, you could modify it (or a copy of it) by using the methods `removeAll` or `retainAll`:

Keep all items in `ids` that are not present in `removeIds`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val ids = mutableListOf(20, 30, 40, 42, 50, 60)
    val removeIds = listOf(20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
    ids.retainAll { it !in removeIds }
    println(ids)
}
```

or remove all items from `ids` that are present in `removeIds`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val ids = mutableListOf(20, 30, 40, 42, 50, 60)
    val removeIds = listOf(20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
    ids.removeAll { it in removeIds }
    println(ids)
}
```

Both `main`s reduce `ids` to just `[42]` in these examples and output exactly that.

Unfortunately, this will not work on immutable `List`s, you would have to make it a `MutableList` first, preferably by using `toMutableList()` or anything similar.